# Term for appending "-esque" or "-ish" to a a word to form an adjective

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, terminology

What is the name of the term for when someone transforms a noun into an adjective by appending `-esque` or `-ish` to the end of the noun? I see this in cases where an appropriate adjective doesn't readily come to mind or the word itself is somewhat esoteric.

For example, when a colleague was trying to differentiate between the tastes of a food, he said the food tasted "capsaicin-ish" to describe the "piquantness" as opposed to the flavor (spice) or physical temperature (heat) of the dish.

Another example was when a friend had a sore throat, and a deep voice as a result. We noted he sounded very "Batman-esque".

Is there an official term this transform?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you hoping for a word that *specifically* means creating the adjectival form by adding either ***-esque*** or ***-ish*** (and *not* by adding the more common ***-y***)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for ***[macaronic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/macaronic):***

> - Of or containing a mixture of vernacular words with Latin words or with vernacular words given Latinate endings: macaronic verse.
> - Of or involving a mixture of two or more languages.

The Free Dictionary

Comment: So `-esque` comes from French, but what language does `-ish` come from?

Comment: @w00t - from German: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ish

Comment: Aha super interesting! Although I was really hoping for there to be some term like "diminutive form" for it, like "comparative form". A making-vaguer-word. Ish.